# Will integer zero template parameter be optimized out?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a template class:

```
template <int foo>
class Bar {
private:
    int data[10];

public:
    int getValue(int index) {return data[index + foo];}
    ...
}
Bar<0>  bar;
// Codes to fill bar's data[] here ...
int retValue = bar.getValue(2);
```

Since the template parameter is zero, when I declare `bar`, I wonder if the zero can/will be optimized out (anything add zero remains itself), when the data index (i.e. `index + foo`) is calculated.

In other word, when an instance of a template class is initiated, will the integer template parameter be treated as a parameter, or a constant, at the time of initiation.

Comment: Template parameters are compile time constants. I'm pretty sure that `index + 0` will be optimized as just `index`. Check the assembly if you want to be sure.

Comment: The word "optimized out" insinuates that there's some kind of mandatory execution semantics behind the operator `+`. I think that's not a healthy attitude to take. First and foremost, expressions and operators are part of the *language* used to describe *values*. Execution on a machine comes much later. When I see `2 + 3`, I would never think that there would be some kind of associated machine instructions. I would just thing "five".

Comment: It's a constant, it will be treated as a constant. Each specialization of the template will have a different `getValue(int)` function which adds a different constant to the index, and for the `Bar<0>` case it won't add anything.

Comment: The only way to be sure ist to inspect the generated assembly code.

Comment: @user2079303: Why do you answer in a comment? Answer in an _answer_!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wanted to encourage OP to go ahead and check the assembly to find out for themselves and hopefully provide an answer to their own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc will definitely optimize that addition out completely whatever the value of the constant `<foo>`. With `-O2` your `getValue()` method generates the following assembly language on x86 with 32-bit `int` types when `<foo>` is zero:

```
  Bar<0>  bar;
// Codes to fill bar's data[] here ...
  return bar.getValue(2);
}
   e:   8b 44 24 10             mov    0x10(%esp),%eax
  12:   c9                      leave  
  13:   c3                      ret
```

To see the assembly language for yourself, compile the translation unit with `-g` and use `objdump -S` on the object file.